# solving PDE equation like Helmholtz equation in 2D

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In my project I need to solve following equation analytically  could anyone help me ? As I read the other questions, my equation seems like   Helmholtz equation
$$
     \triangledown^2 u(x,y) - k_cu(x,y) =0 \quad x,y \in \Omega \\
       u(x,L) = u(x,0),
       u(0,y) = 1
    \quad x \in [0,L] , y \in [0,L]  $$

Comment: Shouldn't you have another boundary condition at $x=L$?

Comment: Also another boundary condition needed at $y =0$ and/or $y=L$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  actually in my problem at $x = L $ I dont know what happens. I want to know if any approach is available as solution to the these equations.

Comment: I mean, you can try to run separation of variables, but without the $x=L$ BC, you won't be able to select the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary conditions you have don't uniquely specify the solution.
 Solutions satisfying your boundary conditions include

(EDITED)
$$ (1-b) e^{\sqrt{k_c} x} + b e^{-\sqrt{k_c} x} + \sum_j a_j \sin(\sqrt{c_j - k_c} x) (\exp(\sqrt{c_j}y) + \exp(\sqrt{c_j}(L-y)))  $$

for any $b$, $a_j$ and $c_j$.

Comment: Really thanks for you answer. would you please explain how you solve this in future boundary condition may change and I want to know how to solve that.

Comment: Separation of variables.

Comment: would you please introduce a tutorial about this technique according to my problem.

Comment: Google "separation of variables" and you'll find lots of tutorials and lecture notes.

Comment: Oops: solution was not quite right: will edit.

Comment: would also explain what is  $b$ in your solution ?

Comment: It can be any constant.